# Plans for labor day weekend (live in New York City)

Tags: usa, budget, sightseeing, new-york-city

Me and a bunch of friends (20s) are looking for a nice place to chill over labor day weekend. We are looking to spend $500 each for the entire trip. And we live around New York.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi YuanH, and welcome to Travel.SE.  I understand your reasoning behind such a  question - but the aim of travel.SE is to go for specific Questions and Answers, not big discussions.  There were several votes to close this as not specific enough and not well formed eonough.  Perhaps if you were ask about some specific destinations you had in mind, and which of them would be more suited to people in their 20s?  We're trying to avoid open-ended questions.